# basic android app that connects with Instagram and will allow

Tags: android, instagram

basic android app that connects with Instagram and will allow people to login to their account and view their feed through my app, how is this possible? i know i need instagram api but what need i should work with this api

Comment: You need to use the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your APP would need to interface with Instagram using Instagram's API.

http://instagram.com/developer/